# How to create this function?

Tags: function-construction, programming

Let vowels:= {"A","E","I","O","U"}

Let alphabet be some CharacterRange, i.e.:

```
CharacterRange["A","F"]
```

or even

```
CharacterRange["A","Z"]
```

Now, is it possible to define a function fun[n_], such that:

f[1]=

```
Map[StringJoin[#] &, Select[
   Map[# &, Tuples[alphabet, 1]],
   (MemberQ[vowels, #[[1]]])
    &]] // Length
```

f[2]=

```
Map[StringJoin[#] &, Select[
   Map[# &, Tuples[alphabet, 2]],
   (MemberQ[vowels, #[[1]]] &&
      MemberQ[vowels, #[[2]]]
     )
    &]] // Length
```

f[3]=

```
Map[StringJoin[#] &, Select[
   Map[# &, Tuples[alphabet, 3]],
   (MemberQ[vowels, #[[1]]] &&
      MemberQ[vowels, #[[2]]] &&
      MemberQ[vowels, #[[3]]]
     )
    &]] // Length
```

and so on...

I see that

```
Tuples[alphabet,3]
```

can be written as

```
Tuples[alphabet,n]
```

but how about the logical construction, (that is where I get lost) ?

```
   (MemberQ[vowels, #[[1]]] &&
      MemberQ[vowels, #[[2]]] &&
      MemberQ[vowels, #[[3]]]
.
.
.
      MemberQ[vowels, #[[n]]]
     )
```

Comment: What does your function do in words?

Comment: What is it that you don't understand @MarcoB ? - Oddly when I pose a question in only words, they ask me to produce code.

Comment: Including code is great. I would always prefer that code be accompanied by an explanation of what it does or is supposed to do. It is sometimes possible to improve code by re-implementing the ultimate goal in a radically different way, rather than trying to understand what existing code does and fixing it. In this case, you accepted an answer that ultimately boiled down to `Intersection[vowels, alphabet]`, but it took Syed a few iterations to get there. I suspect that, if you had described your goal, we would have gotten there quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following helps. Please let me know if it doesn't.

```
vowels = {"A", "E", "I", "O", "U"};
alphabet = CharacterRange["A", "Z"];


func[vowels_List, alphabet_List, n_] := 
 Module[{t = Tuples[alphabet, n]}, 
  StringJoin @@@ Pick[t, AllTrue[#, MemberQ[vowels, #] &] & /@ t] // 
   Length
  ]
```

---

**Usage**

```
func[vowels, alphabet, #] & /@ Range[3]
```

> `{5, 25, 125}`

---

**EDIT**

```
f2[n_] := (Pick[vowels, MemberQ[alphabet, #] & /@ vowels] // Length)^n
```

or even simpler:

```
CountsBy[alphabet, MemberQ[vowels, #] &]
```

Once the `vowels` in `alphabet` are counted, it would be more efficient to generate the tuples instead of the other way round. I don't know of the larger picture, so I will let you decide.

---

**Come to think of it**

`Intersection[vowels, alphabet]`

and then make tuples.

Comment: Looks nice. Will thest this. - Update: Done, it works.

Comment: Can you please explain this part of the solution?
Map[AllTrue[#, MemberQ[vowels, #] &] &, Tuples[alphabet, 1]] Especially the use of two times # & ? Is there a more verbose form of this?

Comment: The inner `&` is for checking membership in the vowels list. The outer`&` is for `AllTrue` establishing that all entries in the sublists are vowels. A less verbose form e.g., for 2-tuples would be: `And @@@ Map[MemberQ[vowels, #] &, Tuples[alphabet, 2], {2}]`

Comment: @niloderoock Even shorter, e.g.; `SubsetQ[vowels, #] & /@ Tuples[alphabet, 2]`